# Can't integrate Spring Boot Admin Server 2 and Spring Boot Admin Client 2 with Spring Boot 2 in a single application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I'm migrating an application from Spring Boot to Spring Boot 2. Previously we had to use Spring Boot Admin Server and Client in a single application (i.e. the application was both a server and a client at the same). That is weird but we have to continue use it the same way at least for now.

At first I decided to make it work using a demo project:
https://github.com/dmitrysenkovich/spring_boot_admin_2_not_working

However, I'm getting an error:

```
ApplicationRegistrator: Failed to register application as Application(name=spring-boot-admin-sample-servlet, managementUrl=http://localhost:8080/actuator, healthUrl=http://localhost:8080/actuator/health, serviceUrl=http://localhost:8080/actuator/admin) at spring-boot-admin ([http://localhost:8080/instances]): 404 null. Further attempts are logged on DEBUG level
```

Spring Boot version is 2.0.4.RELEASE and Spring Boot Admin Client/Server is 2.0.2.

Hope one can make it work. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Johannes Edmeier (the creator of Spring Boot Admin) answered me on GitHub here:
https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/889.

> If you set the spring.boot.admin.context-path, you also have to
>   include this suffix in the spring.boot.admin.client.url

It works!

Answer (score 0):

you can set application.yml to this

```
spring:
  boot:
    admin:
      client:
        url: http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin
        instance:
          service-url: http://127.0.0.1:8080
      context-path: /admin
```

this in my app for springboot2.6.2 success